# How can I disable a subset of buttons which were created using ng-repeat in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build a quiz web application using AngularJS. The quiz questions are structured like this:

```
$scope.quiz = [
  {
    'q': 'For what period would archaeologists first begin to find permanent human settlements?',
    'options': [{ 'value': 'The Paleolithic'} , { 'value': 'The Classical Era'} , {'value' : 'The Bronze Age'} , { 'value': 'The Neolithic'}],
    'answer': 'The Neolithic',
    'difficulty': 2
  },
  {
    'q': 'Which of the following civilizations shares the most in common with the Harappan civilization found in the Indus River Valley?',
    'options':[{ 'value': 'The Mogul Empire in India'} , { 'value': 'The Tokugawa Shogunate in Japan'} , {'value' : 'The Olmec civilization in Mesoamerica'} , { 'value': 'The Athenian city- state in ancient Greece'}],
    'answer': 'The Olmec civilization in Mesoamerica',
    'difficulty': 6
  },
  {
    'q': 'Identify the important original contribution of the Hebrew culture to the civilizations in the Middle East and Mediterranean during the Classical Period.',
    'options':[{ 'value': 'Monotheism'} ,{ 'value': 'Written legal code'} , {'value' : 'Phonetic alphabet'} , { 'value': 'Priest caste'}],
    'answer': 'Monotheism',
    'difficulty': 5
  },
  {
    'q': 'Confucianism established political and social systems in China while what other philosophy contributed significantly to China’s medical practices and art and architecture?',
    'options':[{ 'value': 'Legalism'} ,{ 'value': 'Shintoism'} , {'value' : 'Hinduism'} , { 'value': 'Daoism'}],
    'answer':'Daoism',
    'difficulty': 3
  }
];
```

I use nested ng-repeat's to show the questions and options for each question:

```
<div class='question' ng-repeat='question in quiz | orderBy: difficulty' value='{{$index}}'>
    <h3>{{$index+1}}. {{question.q}}</h3>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-block' ng-repeat='option in question.options' ng-click='submitOption(option.value, question.answer, question.q)' ng-disabled='' ng-data='{{question.q}}'>
        <input type='checkbox'> <strong>{{option.value}}</strong>
    </button>
</div>
```

When I click on an option, I want all the options for that questions to be disabled, but if I simply set `ng-disabled='true'` in the `ng-click='submitOption()'` function, all options for all questions will be disabled. How can I make it so that the options are disabled for one question at a time as I proceed with the quiz?

I have been thinking of passing data (question.q) from the first ng-repeat scope to the nested ng-repeat and adding the attribute `ng-disabled='true'` only to the option buttons with `ng-data='{{question.q}}'`.

Comment: How about using `radio` buttons instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `submitted` property to questions in the quiz, then changing `submitOption` to take `question`:

`submitOption(option.value, question)`

In `submitOption`, you can access `question.answer` and `question.q` and set `question.submitted` to `true`.

You can then use `ng-disabled='question.submitted'` to disable the options for that question only.